# Can I get an integer value from a list box populate with DataRowView?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to get an integer value from a DataRowView?  I have a list box with datasource set to a binding source.  I would like to be able to do this:

```
dim num as integer
num = lstBox.SelectedValue
```

But I receive an InvalidCastException:

> Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

This is how I fill my list box:

```
myDataAdapter("SELECT CustID FROM Customers", cn)
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Customers")
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataSet
myBindingSource.DataMember = "Customers"
lstBox.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

**EDIT:
I have one list box this works for and one it doesn't, so far.  The only difference that I notice is: the one that works, the Query in the data apapter retrieves and auto number from my access table, the one that does not work, the Query in the data adapter retrieves a number.**

Or, is there another way I should go about this?

The application that I am trying to make is a form with a list box for CustID, OrderID, ItemID, and others.  The CustID is from table Customers, OrderID is from table Orders, and ItemID is from table Items.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, I have similar, but would query TWO columns... CustomerName and CustID.
Then, in the combobox, have the DisplayMember property set to "CustomerName" and the ValueMember propert set to the "CustID".